# Is there any tool to solve non-linear equation which has measurement errors both in independent and dependent variables?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

My equation is :

$R = \beta1 * \cos(\theta) + \beta2 * \sin(\theta)$ ,

where independent variable $\theta$ and dependent variable R has errors with variance $\sigma_{\theta}^2$ and $\sigma_{R}^2$ respectively. How to solve for $\beta1$ and $\beta2$ by accounting for errors in variables?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you looking for the smallest $\beta$? Your question seems incomplete to me

Comment: @skr thank you for your reply. I am looking for $\beta$ which is closest to the ideal one. In other words minimizing the residual errors $\sum(R-\beta1*\cos(\theta) - \beta2*\sin(\theta))^2$

Comment: You know the mean as well for $R$ and $\theta$. Also, do you know what probability distribution they follow?

Comment: @skr The error on $R$ and $\theta$ have $\mu = 0$, and of gaussian distribution.

Comment: You are looking for a numerical solution only ? Or an analytical solution?

Comment: @skr I am not sure what is more feasible in the case.